# adding a share button for Facebook on a Wordpress site

Tags: php, wordpress, facebook, facebook-sharer

I am trying to add a few social media share buttons to a Wordpress site I am working on and am using this for Facebook:

```
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=<?php the_permalink();?>" title="Share on Facebook." target="_blank"><img src="/img/facebook-blue.png" alt="Share this on facebook!" /></a>
```

but it is not seeming to work, it produces the correct link when I inspect the code "http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http://myurl/post-name" but when I click it I get this error on Facebook:
[image]

Comment: Give us the actual URL you're passing it.

Comment: (Also, chances are you need to run `the_permalink()` through `urlencode()` to escape special characters.)

Comment: @ceejayoz I'm working locally, the url is: http://localhost:8080/videos/test-2-testing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I'm working locally, the url is: localhost:8080/videos/test-2-testing

You'll find Facebook's sharer.php won't work with *any* localhost URLs.

The sharer scrapes an image, title, and description from the URL it's passed. As it can't access localhost (and allowing it to *try* actually would create [potential security holes](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/95650/is-allowing-unfiltered-curl-request-from-a-website-a-vulnerability) for Facebook), you get this error.

It'll likely work just fine in production, although you'll want to urlencode the URL, like this:

```
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=<?php echo urlencode(get_permalink()) ?>" ...>
```

Comment: thank you!! I just pushed it to production to test and it works great, thank you for the urlencode tip also.

Comment: should this work on mobil devices, I'm having an issue there now?

Answer (score -3):

1. In Your WordPress Admin Area, select Plugins > Add New from the menu.
2. Search for “ShareThis”
3. Install the “ShareThis: Share Buttons and Sharing Analytics” plugin.
4. Activate the Plugin.

This plugin can give you a facebook share button at the bottom and other buttons as well. This is what I use without having to write the code myself.